# Coordinator Layout scrolling flags inside container

Tags: android

Good Day,
I have `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/heading_size" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/top_static_banner"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <com.app.customviews.filter.FilterPanel
                android:id="@+id/filter_panel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/products_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/menu_divider"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/product_row_width"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`FilterPanel` is a child of `FrameLayout`

I have faced with the problem, that android ignore `app:layout_scrollFlags` inside `LinearLayout` container.
I would like add flags to `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`, but how to implement that ?

Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it is very simple:

`AppBarLayout` is a child of `LinearLayout`, so I removed `LinearLayout` from layout, and add `android:orientation="vertical"` for `AppBarLayout`, now I can do what I need.